# Как повысить права для переименования файла?

Tags: c#, файлы, windows-10

```
var f = @"C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe";
var f2 = @"C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe.bak";
File.Move(f1, f2);
```

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" в
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Отказано в доступе по данному пути.

Как сделать повышение прав как например в IObitUnlocker?

Comment: может вам нужен банальный запрос на повышение прав? ну чтобы при запуске выскочило окно UAC

Comment: А если не секрет, для чего вам это? Ума не приложу, какое может быть этому незловредное применение.

Comment: Вам для начала стоит как следует разобраться с устройством прав доступа в Windows. Некоторые вещи невозможно сделать без "шаманства", даже обладая правами администратора через родные интерфейсы Windows, не говоря даже о .NET со всеми его специфическими ограничениями. И все эти ограничения для того, чтобы система сохраняла работоспособность независимо от уровня "незнаний" пользователя. Да есть специальный софт, но реальная необходимость в нем бывает крайне редко, чаще это признак того, что вы что-то делаете неправильно либо целенаправленно нарушаете работу системы.

Comment: VladD  Эти процессы не нужны и их нельзя отключить штатными средствами. Отключение сервисов ничего не даёт. Процессы остаются. Этот процесс от кортаны.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы пытаетесь работать с файлом в так называемом защищенном каталоге. Например Windows, Program Files и им подобные. В новых операционных системах Win7? Win8 и подозреваю в Win10, у вас не получиться что то сделать с файлами в этих каталогах. Работайте с файлами в незащищенных каталогах, типа мои документы.

Comment: Разницы нет что переименование происходит на другой незапущенной системе? Вручную и с пмощью file.move неполучилось.
А IObitUnlocker справился с преименование.